# What happens when EditText has a null?

Tags: android, android-edittext, nullreferenceexception

I have a method like:

```
public String get_Rid_something () {return((EditText)mParent.findViewById(Rid_something)).getText().toString();}
```

If there is no text in the EditText box, what happens, will there be an exception? Or will toString() just return the null for the string without an exception?

I have a bunch of these, so I'd like to efficiently fix each one so that they would return "0" if the text is null - hopefully without bracketing it with a try...catch construct.

Is there an "if" statement I could put in there to see if the string is null and return "0" if it is? Could I do something like:

```
if (((EditText)mParent.findViewById(Rid_something)).getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    return "0"; } else {...}
```

Any other suggestion of a better way to do this?

TIA!

Comment: Probably returns `""` (empty string). Why don't you make a test project and tell us?

Comment: Well why dont you try that yourself?

Comment: use like this editext.getText().toString().trim();

Comment: @Paul see my answer and tell me if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the EditText has no contents, it will return a blank string, or a "" In order to return with 0, simply set up an if statement:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) mParent.findViewById(Rid_something);
String string = editText.getText().toString().trim();
if (string.equals("")) {
    return "0"; 
} else {
    return string;
}
```

This will return 0 if blank, or the contents if not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it worked! To those who marked my question negatively, I was thinking along these lines, but I wanted to see if there was something I was missing and if there was any better/cleverer way to do this before I spent time on this way.